# Why do I get a data type mismatch when trying to update an Access database ? ( with autonumber)

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2010, type-mismatch

I'm trying to update a customer table from VB.NET with the following SQL statement:

```
Dim SQLstr As String = "UPDATE tblKlant SET NaamFirma='" & naamFirma & "', Straat='" & straat & "', Nummer = '" & nummer & "', Gemeente='" & gemeente & "', Postcode='" & postcode & "', TEL='" & tel & "', Fax='" & fax & "',Gsm='" & gsm & "', BtwNr='" & btwNr & "', Email ='" & email & "', Website='" & website & "', IBAN ='" & IBAN & "', BIC='" & BIC & "' WHERE ID='" & CInt(id) & "';"
mainForm.SQLcommand(SQLstr)
```

The error lies in the `WHERE ID='" & CInt(id) & "';"` part. This gives me an error:

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Cause when I replaced it with something else the query worked. The ID is an autonumber by the way. I know you can't update an autonumber but you must be able to use it in the WHERE clause.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `WHERE ID='" & CInt(id) & "';"` the single ticks around the CINT(ID) tell access it is a string.  use: `WHERE ID=" & CInt(id) & " ;"` and use parameterized queries

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! It worked :P

Comment: While the comment made by @Plutonix gave you a solution, the most important part of that comment was **use parameterized queries**, which would prevent this problem from ever happening in the first place and will prevent SQL injection. You shouldn't just ignore it.